# How can I use the Chrono library to get seconds?

Tags: date, time, rust, seconds, rust-chrono

I can get the date, the hours, minutes, seconds and nanoseconds in the date format, but I can't get seconds as a floating point or integer number.

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    let local: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
    println!("{}", local); 
}
```

I have already read the docs.

Comment: The seconds from when? And have you really read the documentation? Either [`timestamp`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.timestamp) or [`second`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/trait.Timelike.html#tymethod.second) look like they could be your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem using the function `timestamp` as written in the docs.
It didn't work before because I forgot to use the brackets to call `timestamp`.

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let local: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
    println!("{}", local.timestamp()); // I forgot the brackets after timestamp
}
```

Thanks to [mcarton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511792/how-can-i-use-the-chrono-library-to-get-seconds#comment79977895_46511792).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Timelike::second`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/trait.Timelike.html#tymethod.second):

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let local: DateTime<Local> = Local::now();
    println!("{}", local.second()); 
}
```